# GC overhead limit exceeded. Read file in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection, readfile

I want a efficient code to do this.

When i run this code, after several minutes code run very slowly and CPU usage is high.

When read file and write `wholeDocument` in database , after several minutes Java compiler show `Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

```
String wholeDocument = "";
try {
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(files));
    String line;
    int count = 0;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("<page>")) {
            wholeDocument = line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                wholeDocument = wholeDocument + "\n" + line;
                if (line.contains("</page>")) {
                    System.out.println(count++);
                    wholeDocument = "";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `StringBuilder`.  Or, better yet, use an XML parser.

Comment: Yes, as @SLaks have said, you're creating too many string objects. Instead, use StringBuilder. If possible, reuse StringBuilder by setting its length to 0.

Comment: it works well. but i want to save "wholeDocument" into database. I create a Class from it and save to databse .I use Hibernat to store Object into database . my code to store it in database is :

    public void addPageToDatabase(Page page) {
        session.save(page);
        if(counter%3000 == 0) {
            commit();
        }
        counter++;
}

Comment: but after store 56400 ("wholeDocument") into database , I have same problem.
and If i do not create new Page Class to store into database and use one Page Object , comiler show this error :
"Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of Database_package.Page was altered from 1 to 8751"
how to store 86000 String ("wholeDocument") in database?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that Strings are immutable data types in java. This means that every time you do String = String + String, it's creating a brand new string and leaving the old one in memory. If you use StringBuilder (or StringBuffer for thread safety) you can safely "append" new strings to an existing one without fear of overusing memory.

Ex:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("New String");
```